# jprofiler overhead between two test runs in java

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, jprofiler

I have two classes

Queue Writer = this class marshal the object and store xml in Message Queue(RabbitMQ)
DB Writer = this class read xml from queue and un-marshal the xml and save into database.

Now I have doing comparison either should use xml( using jaxb) or use json( using jackson) for better performance.

I made a test of 100,000 records ,and both have taken the same time.

Then I download jprofiler and  made two test. But actually , I have used this tool first time and I am not able to find the difference, accurately.

can you please tell me , on what area i can find the overhead between two test.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your filter settings, so that only your own packages are included. Then, profiled the test with CPU data recording enabled and save a snapshot to disk (Session->Save).

With "Session->Compare Snapshots in New Window" you can compare the call tree for both snapshots (CPU comparison->Call tree comparison) and find out where the differences in execution times come from.